# How to treat '<attribute 'dtype' of 'numpy.generic' objects>' error?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, typeerror

After installing pypfopt and u-numpy, `dataframe.info()` command shows this error.

```
TypeError: Cannot interpret '<attribute 'dtype' of 'numpy.generic' objects>' as a data type
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I happened to mix my versions and I encountered the problem today. I managed to fix it.
Both codes in jupyter gave me an error: TypeError: Cannot interpret '<attribute 'dtype' of 'numpy.generic' objects>' as a data type

```
df.info() 
df.categorical_column_name.value_counts().plot.bar()
```

I got the error: TypeError: Cannot interpret '<attribute 'dtype' of 'numpy.generic' objects>' as a data type

This is how i fixed it

Inside jupyter:
Check numpy version:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.__version__)
```

To upgrade:

```
!pip3 install numpy --upgrade
```

Inside Command line check numpy version:
python

```
import numpy
print(numpy.__version__)
```

if versions are not the same choose whether to upgrade/downgrade:
To upgrade:

```
$pip install numpy --upgrade
```

To downgrade just specify the version

If you have python environment installed:
Go to the right folder:
Check the installed version:

```
$pipenv --version
```

To verify if you have a pip environment installed for that folder:
On your terminal Go to the folder and type:

```
$pipenv --version
```

If there is a pipenv it will show the version and if there is none it won't.

check numpy version

```
$python
>>> import numpy
#prints the version
>>> print(numpy__version__)
```

To upgrade the version:

```
>>>exit()
```

#To install the latest version don't specify the version

```
$pipenv install numpy
```

#if you want to downgrade specify the version

```
$pipenv install numpy=version_type
```

Do the same for pandas. Note that with pandas if your pandas environment is 1.2.3 on the jupyter notebook upgrade with `!pip install pandas==1.2.3` or just `!pip install pandas --upgrade --user`.

Note that if the commands are giving you an error always include `--user` at the end of the command.

To create a new environment using miniconda and install updated packages follow the link [https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/install.html][1]

Run the following commands from a terminal window:

1. `conda create -n name_of_my_env python`
   This will create a minimal environment with only Python installed in it. To put your self inside this environment run:

`source activate name_of_my_env`
On Windows the command is:
2. `activate name_of_my_env`

The final step required is to install pandas. This can be done with the following command:

`conda install pandas`

To install a specific pandas version:

3. `conda install pandas=0.20.3`

I prefer using the latest version of pandas 1.2.3

However the first method should solve your problem. Always restart your notebook by closing and reopening it.

I will stick around to see if you are winning. But this will resolve your problem. The problem is caused by the versions of numpy and pandas
[1]: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/install.html

Answer (score 13):

I fixed this type error downgrading `numpy` version to `1.16.5`.

Try it!

Use code below in your `jupyter` notebook to downgrade your `numpy`:

`!pip install numpy==1.16.5`

My `pandas` version: `0.24.2`

Comment: My pandas version is 1.0.x and also required numpy==1.16 to work..

Comment: Solved the problem even in Datbricks. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

downgrading to numpy==1.19.5 works

Use below command to downgrade in anaconda prompt:

`python -m pip install numpy==1.19.5`

Comment: You can use the jupyter notebook to downgrade the NumPy version. Use command: pip install numpy==1.19.5

Answer (score 4):

Here's a link to the `numpy` issue associated with this error:  https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/18355.  A succinct fix is given there (in https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/18355#issuecomment-1029684903):

```
pip install --upgrade numpy
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because of the non-compatibility of NumPy and pandas versions. I couldn't downgrade my NumPy for some odd reasons as others suggested from Anaconda. But found this link helpful
[Downgrading **pandas**](https://github.com/nilmtk/nilmtk/issues/919)
to **1.3** and with the existing **NumPy** version set at **1.20.1**, helped me to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, restarting the kernel fixed the error. Hope it saves someone time as I was reading pandas source code to figure out what the hell was happening :))

Answer (score 1):

Just go to the terminal provided in Jupyter Notebook by clicking "New" and then "Terminal" inside "New" and type:

***`pip install pandas --upgrade`***

this will fix the error
as it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by updating all packages in my Anaconda Navigator Environments

Answer (score -1):

U might have the latest version of NumPy which may not be compatible, so downgrade your NumPy version. I have downgraded to 1.17.2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30690957)