# Pandas Profiling, profile_report method error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plotly, pandas-profiling

I installed `pandas-profiling` with pip for jupyter notebook (not using conda!), and everything was working fine, until I installed `plotly`

Now, when I try to use the `df.profile_report()` method, I get the following error:

> DispatchError: Function <code object pandas_missing_bar at 0x12c62e500, file "/Users/myuser/myvenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas_profiling/model/pandas/missing_pandas.py", line 18>

Please advise,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got the same error here.

This is what I did to solve this issue:

Uninstall all following dependencies and then install them again with these specific versions:

```
pandas-profiling==2.7.1
Jinja2==3.0.3
itsdangerous==2.0.1
Flask==1.1.1
```

Reference: https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/4494

After doing that you may get this error while trying to generate a ProfileReport.

```
TypeError: Cannot interpret '<attribute 'dtype' of 'numpy.generic' objects>' as a data type
```

You can also solve this one by installing this specific version of numpy:

```
pip install numpy==1.16.5 --force-reinstall
```

Reference: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66563463/how-to-treat-attribute-dtype-of-numpy-generic-objects-error](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/4494)

Worked for me, hope it helps you!

Comment: Cool! I ended up creating different venvs for profiling and for publication-grade plots, but this works!