# df.info() results in an error. all other methods of pandas/Numpy works fine

Tags: pandas

I cannot execute **df.info()**. it results in an error:

TypeError: Cannot interpret '<attribute 'dtype' of 'numpy.generic' objects>' as a data type.

I've read some solutions regarding the versions of the libraries, but I'm not sure what should I do.

I've checked the versions in Jupyter:

Numpy version: 1.21.5

pandas version: 1.0.1

Thank you for any help!

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66941626/18938956

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.